# Django form not creating object

Tags: python, django, forms

Django newbie, so sorry in advance! Form shows all the fields, but the form.is_valid() returns false always. The thing is that a form with exact same procedure works, but not this. Code is attached

view.py

```
def signup(request):
    form ="jugar"
    if request.method =="POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userform = form.save(commit=False)
            userform.save()
            return redirect('minerva:login')
        else:
            form = UserForm()
    return render(request,'minerva/signup.html',{'form':form},)
```

signup.html

```
{%extends 'minerva/base.html'%}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %}
{%block slider %}
{%endblock%}

{% block body %}
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <form method="POST" id="contact-form" class="post-form, contact-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default, button button-mini">SignUp!</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Forms.py

```
from .models import Post, Comment, Message, CustomUser
from django import forms
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('author', 'content',)
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('sender' , 'receiver', 'msg_content',)
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username' , 'email' , 'password' , 'ProfileImage' , 'MasterOf', 'intro',)
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ProfileImage = models.ImageField()
    MasterOf = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    intro = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: Unrelated: it is ___extremely___ bad practice to store plain-text passwords.

Comment: Yes I know, I was trying to debug if that was the problem

Comment: Try with `print(form.errors.as_data())` to look the error

Comment: Shows no error with print(form.errors.as_data())

Comment: Your `CustomUser` model includes an `ImageField` but your form doesn't set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` - worth trying with that set.